# Is there a way to expand a div on click with-out using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there a way to re-create the following code but with-out using jQuery as I have to use Wix for a client?

```
<style>
#hover {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
}
</style>

<div id="hover">    
</div>   

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
 $("#hover").click(function(){
        $("#hover").css("width", "500px");
        $("#hover").css("transition", "all 1s");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: yes of course, just write it in plane javascript. `document.getElementById().addEventListener` etc put the `transition` in css and update the width in javascript, or better yet use a class and add/remove with js

Comment: a div called `hover` with a `click` event is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full CSS solution:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">
<div class="my-div">
  My content here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-div {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #777;
  background: #ccc;
  display: none;
}

#toggle:checked ~ .my-div {
  display: block;
}
```

The div will appear checking the input checkbox.

Comment: @tPlummer, Awesome! I like the checkbox technique, it would most likely be useful in a future project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('hover');
anchor.onclick = function() {
  this.style.width = '500px';
  this.style.transition = 'all 1s';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var div = document.getElementById('hover')
div.onclick = function () {
    this.style.width = '500px'
    this.style.transition = 'all 1s'
    this.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
}
```

i.e. when there's two words, background-color becomes backgroundColor

The difference between this and the jQuery solution:

Pure JavaScript is usually faster because you save from the extra function calls (most uses you wouldn't notice though), and also it treats it as a single '1' element so if the div doesn't exist you'll get an error in the console. The error would prevent the rest of the script from running.

Whereas jQuery treats things as arrays, so if no matches then array length of zero which is no error.

Instead of `getElementById` you can use `querySelector('#hover')` for CSS queries, check browser support though.

Comment: Thanks for code and explanation hopefully it will come in super handy

Comment: I want this function to run on multiple divs, therefore I should be using class, how do I get it to look for a class instead of an id?

Comment: `var divs = document.querySelectorAll(...)` `for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) divs[i].onclick = ...` The reference to `this` will cause the correct div that you clicked to be the one div that was affected.

Comment: @MatthewHammond, I usually would use CSS as suggested by CodeGodie instead of JavaScript for simple things, but it is up to you to decide which is best for your project.

Comment: So would I however it doesn't work for my project, here is my project at the moment, but still having problems, I don't suppose you can help me, I can seem to work out how to make it change the css of another class other than the one clicked. https://jsfiddle.net/txoyuvqn/1/

Comment: Make a `var whattochange = ...`, and then replace `this` with `whattochange`. If you have further difficulty, start a new question, and give me a link to it..

Comment: @GeorgeBaily I have made the changes but it's still not working, here is a link to my new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30809503/im-trying-to-make-a-div-width-expand-once-clicking-on-another-div

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with CSS: **[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/qpbv4ftz/2/)**

With this, you will be able to do click events without using Javascript/Jquery.

CSS:

```
#hover {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    transition: all 1s;
}
#hover:target{
    width:500px;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="#hover">
    <div id="hover">    
    </div>
</a>
```