# I'm trying to make a div width expand once clicking on another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make a div expanded once you click on another div. In my case I'm try to make div with some text in it expand when the image is clicked. A link to my JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/txoyuvqn/3/

My javascript that I am using looks like.

```
    var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
var whattochange = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
  divs[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < whattochange.length; i++) {
      whattochange[i].style.width = '500px'
      whattochange[i].style.transition = 'all 1s'
      whattochange[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'
    }
  }, false);
```

However when I click on the class called image it effects all the Text classes, i know it's because were changing the css to all of the text divs, however is there a way to make it only effect the correlating div? Or am I going about creating this in the wrong way?

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" it would be better to provide the exact error message and line number that occurred on. This is available in the Console. Try Googling "check for JavaScript errors" or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a better way, but you could do it like this:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
var whattochange = document.getElementsByClassName('text');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
{
    divs[i].addEventListener("click", function() 
    { 
        var w = document.getElementById(this.id.replace('img', 'text'));
        w.style.width = '800px'
        w.style.transition = 'all 1s'
        w.style.backgroundColor = 'red'      
    });

    whattochange[i].id = 'text' + i;
    divs[i].id = 'img' + i;
}
```

Comment: How would i go about making it retract when clicked again, would I make an if statement see if the div is =800 and if so set width 0px?

Comment: That would work. Something like: if(w.style.width == '800px') w.style.width = '0px' else w.style.width = '800px'

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array, not a single element.

`divs` is an array, and you are correctly using a `for` loop and the index indicator `[i]` after your variable name `divs`.

You need a similar `for` loop for `whattochange`.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
var whattochange = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++)
  divs[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < whattochange.length; i++) {
      whattochange[i].style.width = '800px';
      whattochange[i].style.transition = 'all 1s';
      whattochange[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    }
  }, false);
```

Comment: That works, however now when I click on one it effects all of them where as before it only effected one, sorry to ask as I don't know much about javascript but is there a way to make it open the correct one, like before when we used this.

Answer (score 0):

### See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/txoyuvqn/6/)

**Javascript**

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('image');
  var whattochange = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
  for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
      divs[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
          for (var i = 0; i < whattochange.length; i++) {
              whattochange[i].style.width = '800px';
              whattochange[i].style.transition = 'all 1s';
              whattochange[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
          }
      }, false);
  }
```

You have to be sure that the elements exist if your JavaScript code depends on them. The reason why your fiddle didnt work was because, you was not loading the script after the body has finished loading.

In your code, One way of achieving this is by putting the `<script>` tag at the end of the body like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // code here
</script>
</body>
```

You can also put all your code in a function for the `window.onload` event or use jQuery.